# Amazon Simple Email Services Not Always Working

Tags: php, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have been using Amazon SES for sometime now through the PHP library found [here](http://www.orderingdisorder.com/aws/ses/), now I have new EC2 Debian instance, and SES is not working most of the time, sometimes when I restart the Apache server, SES sends emails for few hours and then stops working again, I get the following error in the server log:

```
[Wed May 23 15:20:01 2012] [error] [client xxxxxxxxxx] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: SimpleEmailServiceRequest::$resource in /path-to/library/aws/ses.php on line 491
[Wed May 23 15:20:01 2012] [error] [client xxxxxxxxxx] PHP Warning:  SimpleEmailService::sendEmail(): 6 Couldn't resolve host 'email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' in /path-to/library/aws/ses.php on line 357
```

ssl mod is enabled on the server.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please ask a question. If this is a support inquiry about the availiability of Amazon SWS, please contact the AWS support: http://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/

Comment: this is not about the availability of Amazon SES, SES works fine on my other instances.

Comment: Why not use Amazon official sdk for php? http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/

Comment: @SergikS : this library was the one provided on SES website, before the PHP sdk was available for SES. I went with you suggestion and used the official sdk, and guess what? I'm getting the same error, and when I reload my Apache server, everything works fine for few hours and then the error comes back. could this be something with my EC2 security group? any help is really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @mohamed: the quoted error message mentions Domain Name resolving, which fails at some point. Can this be due to DNS caching settings of a particular EC2 instance or just a network connection blip, as RyanP@AWS suggests in [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=93308&tstart=0)?

Comment: @SergikS: thanks for input, it's probably something with this particular instance(ami-1e39ca77), I have tried what RyanP@AWS suggested, it didn't work for me, I guess I will replace the image with a different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that worked for me was to get rid of the EC2 instance I was using and replacing it with a different one, since I did, more than a month ago, I have never had this problem again.